# How to use gstreamer to make timestamp of first frame of mp4 start at something other than 0

Tags: encoding, gstreamer, mp4

We're creating a set of videos from multiple cameras, and we need to be able to identify the frames in all videos that correspond to the same moment in time.  However, it's not possible to guarantee that the recorded videos are perfectly in sync, due to variations in machine load or encoding burden during the recording.

A simplified version of the pipeline we're using looks like this:

```
gst-launcher-1.0 -e \
   tcambin serial=33810032 name=source \
   ! timeoverlay shading-value=255 shaded-background=true font-desc=\"Sans, 10\" time-mode=0 \
   ! video/x-raw,format=BGRx,width=1920,height=1080,framerate=15/1 \
   ! videoconvert \
   ! x264enc speed-preset=1 pass=5 bitrate=100000 threads=6 \
   ! mp4mux \
   ! filesink location=out1.mp4
```

This produces a mp4 that correctly seeks to the proper position when given a timestamp, but it will be off by precisely the amount of time displayed in the corner of the first frame.

In a nutshell, I'd like to create an mp4 where the timestamps of the frame correspond to what we're seeing in the timeoverlay - this represents the "true" wall clock time.  As it currently stands, in order to find the frame in video M that corresponds to the frame in video N, we need to compute:

timestamp(N) - offset(N) + offset(M).

Answer (score 0):

Mp4 does not record frame timestamps, it records frame durations. There is not first frame time stamp to set.

Comment: Is it possible to insert a blank frame at position zero with the duration of the offset?